# How can we centre the div in a div with buttons to its left and right?

Tags: html, css

In my code I am trying to put the arrow buttons to the extreme left and right of the div and the `mid` div must be in the middle of the div I have seen manny question on this but not getting the proper answer can Anybody help me what exactly the problem is?.

what I want is the `mid` div can of any size so it is containing the 5 buttons but it may contain more or less that that so how to centre that div so this can be achievable.

```css
#page-nav{
        width:400px;
        border:1px solid;
        height:20px;
}
    
#right{
        float:right;
}
#mid{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='page-nav'>
          
  <button id=left></button>
        
  <div id="mid">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    
  </div>
    
  <button id="right"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `<` in your HTML... the browser will see it as an opening tag. Use special characters instead `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```
<div id='page-nav'>
    <button id="left">&lt;</button>
    <div id="mid">
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
    </div>
    <button id="right">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

Then, to your question. Display the `#mid` div as an inline-block, and add `text-align` to `#page-nav`. Then float both the left and right arrow to the sides.

```
#page-nav {
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid;
    /*height:20px;*/
    text-align: center;
}
#left {
    float: left;
}
#right {
    float:right;
}
#mid {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that I removed the height of `#page-nav` so the buttons wrap nice in it.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zwppd8b/)

Answer (score 4):

Set `display:table` to the parent div and `display: table-cell` with `text-align:center` to the inner div and the left and right buttons

**UPDATE**

It would be better to wrap the left and right buttons in to a div:

```css
#page-nav{
    display: table;
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid;
    height:20px;
}
#left { 
  display:table-cell }
#right{
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:right;
}
#mid{
  display:table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='page-nav'>
   <div id="left">
     <button id="leftBtn">L</button>
   </div>
   <div id="mid">
        <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <button id="rightBtn">R</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using both `table-cell` and `float` is double... I would suggest to use either one of them.

Comment: Thanks @LinkinTED, that's right. Also updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

use

**CSS**

```
#page-nav {
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid;
    height:25px;
    text-align:center;
}
#right {
    float:right;
}
#mid {
    display:inline-block;
}
#left {
    float:left;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4y0y5bj/)

Comment: The `display: inline-block` on `#left` and `#right` have no purpose while you already use float, you can remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I like to stretch things using `text-align: justify;` by using a `span at 100% width`

The con using this method is the space on the bottom.

```
 <div id='page-nav'>

            <button id=left><</button>



 <button>1</button>
        <button>2</button>
        <button>3</button>
        <button>4</button>
        <button>5</button>

        <button id="right">></button>

     <span class="stretch"> </span>

</div>
```

CSS

```
 #page-nav{
        width:400px;
        border:1px solid;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .stretch {
        width:100%;
        height:1em;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhxgt238/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `absolute` position for the arrows and `display:table` for the buttons :

```
#page-nav {
width:400px;
border:1px solid;
height:30px;
position: relative;
}
#left {
position:absolute;
left:0;
height:25px;

/*To center vertically*/
margin:auto;
top:0;
bottom:0;
}
#right {
position:absolute;
right:0;
height:25px;

/*To center vertically*/
margin:auto;
top:0;
bottom:0;
}
#mid {
margin: 0 auto;
width:auto;
display:table;
}
```